# ¿Cómo eliminar un elemento de un array y recorrerlo para evitar un espacio vació? (java)

Tags: java

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo elimino un elemento de un array?, para después recorrerlo así evitando espacios vacíos. Tengo hecho mi código pero, al eliminar por ejemplo un número este vuelve aparecer. ¿Podrían decirme que tengo de mal en mi código?. Otra cosa que también note, es que al ingresar  un numero repetido no me deja volver a ingresar otro numero, es como si ese 5 se duplicara solo :(

---

### Ejercicio propuesto por mi profesor

Hacer un Sistema que pida la longitud del arreglo, este arreglo contendrá puros enteros.

Se tendrá el siguiente menú:

```
1.- Alta de un número
```

El indice de la siguiente posición vacía sera un atributo en la clase donde se encuentra el arreglo.

El arreglo no tendrá números repetidos, ,  si el  numero ya esta en el arreglo se le indicara al usuario que ya existe y que de otro numero.

```
2.- Cambio de número
```

Se pedirá el numero para buscarlo, si se encuentra se pedirá el nuevo numero,  si el  numero ya esta en el arreglo se le indicara al usuario que ya existe y que de otro numero.

```
3.- Eliminar un número
```

Se pedirá el numero, si se encuentra se preguntara si esta seguro de darlo de baja, si es afirmativa la respuesta, los demás números se recorrerán hacia arriba del arreglo para no dejar ningún espacio vació.

```
4.- Imprimir los números
5.- Salir
```

Nota: El Sistema tendrá 2 clases, una donde estará el `main` y la otra donde estará el arreglo de enteros

---

### Clase Main

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestNumero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        Numero_Dos numP;
        int opc1, n, j=0, k = 0, numero = 0, dato = 0;
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos números tendrá el programa?");
        n = leer.nextInt();
        numP = new Numero_Dos(n);
        do {
            System.out.println("1.- Alta de numero");
            System.out.println("2.- Cambio de numero");
            System.out.println("3.- Eliminar un numero");
            System.out.println("4.- Imprimir números");
            System.out.println("5.- Salir");
            opc1 = leer.nextInt();
            switch (opc1) {
                case 1:
                    if (j<n) {
                        j++;
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero por favor");
                        numero=leer.nextInt();
                        if(!numP.numeroRepetido(numero)){
                            numP.setNumero(k++, numero);  
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Este numero ya esta repetido, ingresa otro");
                        }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("No puedes agregar mas números");
                        }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    int pos;
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero que desea cambiar");
                    dato=leer.nextInt();
                    if ((pos = numP.buscarNum(dato)) == -1) {
                        System.out.println("¡El dato no existe en el arreglo!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo numero");
                        numero=leer.nextInt();
                        numP.setNumero(pos, numero);
                        System.out.println("Ingresando números.....");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese que número desea eliminar");
                    dato=leer.nextInt();
                    if ((pos = numP.buscarNum(dato)) == -1) {
                        System.out.println("¡El dato no existe en el arreglo!");
                    } else {
                        numP.borrarNumero(numero);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Los números son: "+ numP.getNumero(i));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } while (opc1 < 5);
    }
}
```

### Clase de Numero

```java
public class Numero_Dos {

    private int arrayN[];

    Numero_Dos(int numero) {
        arrayN = new int[numero];
    }

    public void setNumero(int i, int numero) {
        arrayN[i] = numero;
    }

    public boolean numeroRepetido(int numero) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
            if (arrayN[i] == numero) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int buscarNum(int dato) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
            if (dato == arrayN[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void borrarNumero(int posicion) {
        for (int i = posicion - 1; i < arrayN.length - 1; i++) {
            arrayN[i] = arrayN[i + 1];
        }
    }

    public int getNumero(int i) {
        return arrayN[i];
    }
}
```

---

### Salida

```
run:
¿Cuantos números tendrá el programa?
2
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
1
Ingrese el numero por favor
5
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
1
Ingrese el numero por favor
5
Este numero ya esta repetido, ingresa otro
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
1
No puedes agregar mas números
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
3
Ingrese que numero desea eliminar
5
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
4
Los números son: 5
Los números son: 0
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
3
Ingrese que numero desea eliminar
5
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
4
Los números son: 5
Los números son: 0
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
1
No puedes agregar mas números
1.- Alta de numero
2.- Cambio de numero
3.- Eliminar un numero
4.- Imprimir números
5.- Salir
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por las correcciones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para borrar puedes crear un nuevo arreglo y llenarlo con los elementos del arreglo anterior excluyendo el que está en la posición seleccionada:

```
public void borrarNumero(int posicion) {
    //crear un nuevo arreglo de longitud arrayN -1
    int nuevoArreglo[] = new int[arrayN.length -1];
    //recorrer arreglo anterior
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length - 1; i++) {
        //si i es igual o mayor a la posición tomar el siguiente elemento
        if(i >= posicion){
           nuevoArreglo[i] = arrayN[i + 1];
        }else{
        //tomar elemento en i
        nuevoArreglo[i] = arrayN[i];
        }
    }
    //reemplazar arreglo anterior con el nuevo arreglo
    arrayN = nuevoArreglo;
}
```

> al ingresar un numero repetido no me deja volver a ingresar otro numero

Haz el incremento de la variable `j` solo cuando el número se haya ingresado:

```
if (j<n) {

   System.out.println("Ingrese el numero por favor");
   numero=leer.nextInt();
   if(!numP.numeroRepetido(numero)){
      numP.setNumero(k++, numero);  
      j++;
    }else{
       System.out.println("Este numero ya esta repetido, ingresa otro");
     }
   }else{
     System.out.println("No puedes agregar mas numeros");
   }
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por ayudarme!, es increible esta comunidad :')

Comment: ¡Listo! y muchas gracias compañero :)